# want to call python api in my javascript code. I just want to check that how hello world is called from python and printed in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, api

This is my python code and I want to display it on my html code page layout through button I just want to check that how it is called in javascript.

```
print("hello world")    (savelist.py)
```

And this is my html javascript file

```
<html>`<html>`
<head>
hjgkhkj
</head>`enter code here`
<body>


<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button type="button" id="home" onclick="validate()" value="checkvalue">
<script>
$('#id').click(function(){

 $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:<YOUR SERVERSIDE PAGE URL>,
      cache:false,
      data:<if any arguments>,
      async:asynchronous,
      dataType:json, //if you want json
      success: function(data) {
        <put your custom validation here using the response from data structure >
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        <put your custom code here to handle the call failure>
      }
   });enter code here
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python file wont send anything back on its own. You need to provide a way to process the Ajax requests within the python file and return a JSON response, if thats what you are after. I dunno what kind of set up you have or are looking for so I dunno what else to advise.

Here's a link to requests docs -> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/